# How to set any widget on screen at specific position with responsiveness in flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart

I am trying to set any widget to screen at any position so if user open app in other devices the widget must should remain at that give position , for example if I set widget on 1/4 part of the screen then it should be the same in every device . I tested in simulator from Iphone 8 to Ipad 8th gen.

Below is my code I am using Positioned.fromRect  and passing Offset(dx,dy). I also tried MediaQuery but all in vain . Please guide me even if you find my question stupid.

Reference app [Story click](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.insta.story.maker.pro) or post maker app with pre built in templates.

This is simple constructor.

```
 FlutterSimpleStickerImage(
    this.image, {
    Key key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.viewport,
    this.minScale = 1.0,
    this.maxScale = 2.0,
    this.onTapRemove,
  }) : super(key: key);

   Widget image;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Size viewport;

  final double minScale;
  final double maxScale;
```

A class for positioning widget in stack the Position.fromRect()

```
class _FlutterSimpleStickerImageState extends State<FlutterSimpleStickerImage> {
  _FlutterSimpleStickerImageState();

  double _scale = 1.0;
  double _previousScale = 1.0;

  Offset _previousOffset = Offset(0, 0);
  Offset _startingFocalPoint = Offset(0, 0);
  Offset _offset = Offset(0, 0);

  double _rotation = 0.0;
  double _previousRotation = 0.0;

  bool _isSelected = false;



  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _offset = Offset(0, 0);
    _scale = 1.0;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double  sizewidth=183;
    double  sizeheight=0;


    return Positioned.fromRect(



      rect: Rect.fromPoints(Offset(sizewidth, sizeheight),Offset(sizewidth , sizeheight )),
      child: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Transform(
                transform: Matrix4.diagonal3(Vector3(_scale, _scale, _scale)),
                // ..setRotationZ(_rotation),
                alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onScaleStart: (ScaleStartDetails details) {
                    _startingFocalPoint =  Offset(sizewidth,sizeheight);
                    _previousOffset = Offset(sizewidth,sizeheight);
                    _previousRotation = _rotation;
                    _previousScale = _scale;

                    // print(
                    //     "begin - focal : ${details.focalPoint}, local : ${details.localFocalPoint}");
                  },
                  onScaleUpdate: (ScaleUpdateDetails details) {
                    _scale = min(
                        max(_previousScale * details.scale, widget.minScale),
                        widget.maxScale);

                    _rotation = details.rotation;

                    final Offset normalizedOffset =
                        (_startingFocalPoint - _previousOffset) /
                            _previousScale;

                    Offset __offset =
                        details.focalPoint - (normalizedOffset * _scale);

                    __offset = Offset(max(__offset.dx, -widget.width),
                        max(__offset.dy, -widget.height));

                    __offset = Offset(min(__offset.dx, widget.viewport.width),
                        min(__offset.dy, widget.viewport.height));

                    setState(() {
                      _offset = __offset;
                      // print("move - $_offset, scale : $_scale");
                    });
                  },
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isSelected = !_isSelected;
                    });
                  },
                  onTapCancel: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isSelected = false;
                    });
                  },
                  onDoubleTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _scale = 1.0;
                    });
                  },
                  onLongPress: (){
                    setState(() {
                      widget.image=Container(height: 100,width: 100,color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 150, 0, 1.0),);

                    });

                  },
                  child: Container(child: widget.image),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            _isSelected
                ? Positioned(
                    top: 12,
                    right: 12,
                    width: 24,
                    height: 24,
                    child: Container(
                      child: IconButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle),
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 150, 0, 1.0),
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('tapped remove sticker');
                          if (this.widget.onTapRemove != null) {
                            this.widget.onTapRemove(this.widget);
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void hideRemoveButton() {
    setState(() {
      _isSelected = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Have  you tried using the [Align class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html)?

Comment: Oh thanks man You saved me from insult . thanks bro.